# Django chatterbot

Tags: python, django

I've been practicing with Django Chatterbot by integrating it with a Rest API but I've been having some problems with the functionality. The API is recipe based so the Chatbot View is set up to communicate with the user and find them the perfect recipe to match their inputed ingredients. Here's what the code looks like (sorry its long):

```
state = 'searching'
        filtered_recipes = []

        # Define the get_response() function outside of the post() function
        def get_response(message, state, filtered_recipes):
            # Search for recipes based on ingredients
            if state == 'searching':
                ingredients = extract_ingredients(message)
                filtered_recipes = filter_recipes_by_ingredients(ingredients)

                # Return recipe description if recipe found
                if len(filtered_recipes) != 0:
                    recipe = filtered_recipes[0]
                    state = 'asking_for_url'
                    return JsonResponse({'message': recipe.description + " Would you like the recipe's URL for preparation?"}), state, filtered_recipes

                # This line will only execute if filtered_recipes is empty
                state = 'no_recipes_found'
                return JsonResponse({'message': "I'm sorry, there are currently no recipes available with those ingredients."}), state, filtered_recipes


             # Ask if user wants recipe's URL
            elif state == 'asking_for_url':
                if 'yes' in message.lower():
                    recipe = filtered_recipes[0]
                    print(state)
                    print(filtered_recipes)
                    state = 'recipe_url_provided'
                    return JsonResponse({'message': "Here is the recipe's URL: " + recipe.url + " \n Good luck cooking, I hope your food is delicious!"}), state, filtered_recipes
                elif 'no' in message.lower():
                    state = 'searching'
                    return JsonResponse({'message': "Okay, let me know if you need help with anything else."}), state, filtered_recipes
                else:
                    ingredients = extract_ingredients(message)
                    filtered_recipes = filter_recipes_by_ingredients(ingredients)
                    if len(filtered_recipes) != 0:
                        recipe = filtered_recipes[0]
                        state = 'asking_for_url'
                        return JsonResponse({'message': recipe.description + " Would you like the recipe's URL for preparation?"}), state, filtered_recipes
                    else:
                        state = 'no_recipes_found'
                        return JsonResponse({'message': "I'm sorry, there are currently no recipes available with those ingredients."}), state, filtered_recipes
                
            if state == 'recipe_url_provided':
                state = 'searching'
                return JsonResponse({'message': "Okay, let me know if you need help with anything else. Have fun cooking!"}), state, filtered_recipes


        # Call the get_response() function and update the state variable
        response, state, filtered_recipes = get_response(message, state, filtered_recipes)

        if state == 'asking_for_url':
            response, state, filtered_recipes = get_response(message, state, filtered_recipes)

        return response
```

The problem I'm having here is that the "asking_for_url" state overrides the filtered recipes hence when the user responds "yes" they aren't getting the url for the recipe they want but rather the first recipe in an unfiltered list of recipes. Is there anything I'm missing or any fixes I could make? Thank you

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, the question was how do I fix this? Or is there anything I'm missing generally

Comment: What do you want to fix? What should the output be?

Comment: The output should first have the chatbot return the recipe description that use those ingredients, it's not doing that right now.